# Neodynamic Barcode Professional font display

Tags: fonts, barcode, neodynamic

I use Barcode Professional (by Neodynamic) in an ASP.NET page (see code below).
On Windows Server 2003 the font renders fine, but on Windows Server 2012 it's not acceptable... The source code is identical on each server.

```
<div id="divBarCodeImprm">
     <neobarcode:BarcodeProfessional ID="barCode"
                                            runat="server"
                                            AlternateText=""
                                            Symbology="Code39"
                                            AddChecksum="False"
                                            DisplayStartStopChar="False"
                                            Extended="False"
                                            RenderingMethod="HttpHandler"
                                            AutoSize="True"
                                            BarRatio="3.5"
                                            Monochrome="True"
                                            BackColor="White"
                                            BarHeight="0.5"
                                            HighQualityGif="True"
                                            Font-Size="11em"
                   Font-Names="Trebuchet MS,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif" /> 
</div>
```

Result:

2003: [image: 2003 image]

2012: [image: 2012 image]

How do I control/improve font rendering?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with rendering the issue is :

Windows sever 2003 comes with **Trebuchet MS** v 1.22 , while windows 2008 and later come with **Trebuchet MS** v5.00 .

check **[2003](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=162)** list , and **[2008](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=160)** list.

**Solution :**

- you can either override the installed font package on 2012 with the
  old one of 2003 you find it ok , but i wouldnt recommend this
  solution much.
- you can choose another font family that is already installed on your device , and you feel ok with ( just one family will do ).
- you can install a brand new font family , and use it , to make sure everything works well , use single font family name.